# how to align the input field vertically centered?

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML:

```
<header>
    <div class="image">
        <img class="logo" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b637dcf2d1f68517a316c466585ea1a8?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
    </div>
    <div class="form">
        <input type="text" class="input" name="location" id="location" />
    </div>
</header>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.image {
    float:left;
}
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.form {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/NmP69/1/

Comment: Provide HTML code with a jsfiddle link.

Comment: Provide a height for the `.form` when you use `vertical-align` Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QraX6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/32Xnz/)**

The CSS Change:

```
.form {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display:table-cell;
}

header {
    display: table;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nathan Lee. It worked great as I wanted. You guys rock!!! Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible way of doing it is to use position absolute and negative margin on your image:

```
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

See the result here:
http://jsfiddle.net/WHSKL/